# Need Help Identifying

Tags: microcontroller, components, computer-architecture, hard-drive

This is a Board off a 8tb WD Hard Drive. I plug in the wrong power and i believe the little thing with the S on it is bad. I do not know what it is call or where i could find another, any help would be appreciated. The power coming in from the sata is 12v 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that's failed and not one of the thousand other devices on the board? It's far more likely a semiconductor device has failed than a little passive element like that.

Comment: Because the same one next to it (not in picture) has connectivity though it for the 3v pins and this one dose not.

Comment: All i want to know is what is the part with the S called

Comment: @DaveAlander That doesn't mean anything. You don't know what it is supposed to do or where it leads to. You don't if they both are supposed to do the same thing or not. Furthermore, semiconductor parts tend to fail short, not open.

Comment: ok. if i jump it the hard drive will work. but that's not a fix

Comment: Then just jump it then and move all your data off of it. Plugging in the wrong thing for power (voltage?) tends to damage multiple things, not just one so I would no longer trust the reliability of that drive.

Comment: Is "S" open circuit.  Maybe it is a fuse?

Comment: skvery thats what i think it is. but i am just a guy in a garage

Comment: maybe: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1693108.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Without a schematic this is an educated guess. Based on its location in the power input, it's either a 0 ohm jumper (doesnt seem to be needed there) or shunt or its a fusible resistor. It could be a SMD chip inductor, but those rarely have any top code in the package shown.

Having have blown when power was applied incorrectly (from what was in the comments) it seems to have done its job as a fuse.

It blowing is a symptom of some other issue on the board, so jumping it is not wise. If jumping it works, as mentioned in the comments, copy your data off and dispose of the drive or only use it in non critical use.

Comment: You could try warranty. It's a gamble.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can get a replacement board for $50 But i have to swap some chips and do a some programing to save the data and that not a guaranty. replacing this looks so much easier. I think it is some sort of fuse.